# Calculator: Cannot use ActionListener in a pop up window from my main GUI

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, calculator

I am having a bit of a problem with my calculator. The main "GUI" has the numberpad and a few operators, but I added a JMenuItem for all the trigonmetric functions as in they open up in a new window. I have no problem using the operators on the main GUI (+, -, sqrt, power etc.) but I can´t seem to get the Trigonmetric functions to work at all. I put in further information in comments in my code(Read comment behind the 3rd last instance variable named t).

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame
{
    //TILVIKSBREYTUR    
    JFrame rammi;                //Rammi inniheldur panel
    JPanel pnl;                  //Panel inniheldur takka 
    private final Font BIGGER_FONT = new Font("monspaced", Font.PLAIN, 20); //Letur
    public JTextField txt;       //Textareitur
    private JButton b0;          //b0 - b9 eru númeratakkar
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton b5;
    private JButton b6;
    private JButton b7;
    private JButton b8;
    private JButton b9;
    private JButton bDecPoint;   //Decimal point
    private JButton bc;          //Clear takki, endurstillir textareit
    private JButton bPlus;       //Plús takki
    private JButton bMinus;      //Mínus takki
    private JButton bPower;      //Veldatakki
    private JButton bSqrt;       //Kvaðratrótartakki
    private JButton bDivide;     //Deilingar takki
    private JButton bMult;       //Margföldunar takki
    private JButton bxRoot;       //N-tu rótartakki
    private JButton bEqual;      //Jafnt og takki
    private JButton bPer;        //prósent
    private JButton bAns;        //síðasta útkoma
    private JButton bPi;         //Pi
    private JButton bSvigi1;     //Svigi
    private JButton bSvigi2;     //Svigi
    private JSeparator sep1;     //Separator, skilur að textareit og lyklaborð
    private JSeparator sep2;     //Separatorm skilur að númer og virkja
    public  boolean number;      //tala
    public  boolean degPressed;  //Er Degrees valið ? 
    public  boolean trigOpen;    //Er Trigonmetry flipinn opinn?
    public  boolean trigOpenOp;  //hjálpar breyta fyrir virkni
    public  String  equalOp;     //Strengur fyrir virkja
    public  String ans;
    public  String ansOp;        //Strengur
    private JMenuBar menuBar;    //Menu bar
    private JMenu file;          //Flipi í menu bar
    private JMenuItem trigon;    //Hornaföll
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem deg;  //undirgluggi flipa í menubar
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem rad;  //undirgluggi flipa í menubar

    private Trigonmetry t;      //if I do: private Trigonmetry t = new Trigonmetry then it works
                                //perfectly but if I do that then the Trigonmetry window opens up 
                                //when I open the Calculator but I just want Trigonmetry window
                                //to open up when Trigonmetry MenuItem i pressed 

    private CalculatorOp op = new CalculatorOp();  //CalculatorOp classi sem sér um virkni virkjanna


    public Calculator(){
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI(){
        //TILVIKSBREYTUM GEFID GILDI
        rammi = new JFrame(); 
        degPressed = false;
        trigOpen   = false;
        trigOpenOp = false;
        trigon = new JMenuItem("Trigonmetry");
        pnl = new JPanel();
        txt = new JTextField("0.0");
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        deg = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Degrees");
        rad = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Radians", true);
        number = true;
        equalOp = "=";
        ansOp   = "ANS";
        sep1 = new JSeparator();
        sep2 = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        b0 = new JButton("0");
        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b9 = new JButton("9");
        bc = new JButton("C");
        bPer = new JButton("%");
        bAns = new JButton("ANS");
        bDecPoint = new JButton(".");
        bPlus = new JButton("+");
        bMinus = new JButton("-");
        bPower = new JButton("x^n");
        bSqrt = new JButton("√x");
        bxRoot = new JButton("n√x");
        bDivide = new JButton("/");
        bMult = new JButton("*");
        bEqual = new JButton("=");
        //bSvigi1 = new JButton("(");
        //bSvigi2 = new JButton(")");

        //HÖNNUN RAMMA
        setTitle("GCalc");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(370, 280));

        //STADSETNING HLUTA
        txt.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        txt.setFont(BIGGER_FONT);
        pnl.setLayout(null);
        //tölur og clear
        bc.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(bc);
        bDecPoint.setBounds(10, 190, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(bDecPoint);
        b0.setBounds(70, 190, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b0);
        b1.setBounds(10, 150, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b1);
        b2.setBounds(70, 150, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b2);
        b3.setBounds(130, 150, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b3);
        b4.setBounds(10, 110, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b4);
        b5.setBounds(70, 110, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b5);
        b6.setBounds(130, 110, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b6);
        b7.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b7);
        b8.setBounds(70, 70, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b8);
        b9.setBounds(130, 70, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(b9);
        //virkjar
        bAns.setBorder(null);
        bAns.setBounds(130, 190, 50, 30);
        pnl.add(bAns);
        bPlus.setBorder(null);
        bPlus.setBounds(200, 70, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bPlus);
        bMinus.setBorder(null);
        bMinus.setBounds(240, 70, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bMinus);
        bSqrt.setBorder(null);
        bSqrt.setBounds(240, 150, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bSqrt);
        bPower.setBorder(null);
        bPower.setBounds(200, 150, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bPower);
        bDivide.setBorder(null);
        bDivide.setBounds(200, 110, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bDivide);
        bMult.setBorder(null);
        bMult.setBounds(240, 110, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bMult);
        bxRoot.setBorder(null);
        bxRoot.setBounds(280, 70, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bxRoot);
        bPer.setBorder(null);
        bPer.setBounds(320, 70, 30, 30);
        pnl.add(bPer);
        //bSvigi1.setBorder(null);
        //bSvigi1.setBounds(280, 110, 30, 30);
        //pnl.add(bSvigi1);
        //bSvigi2.setBorder(null);
        //bSvigi2.setBounds(320, 110, 30, 30);
        //pnl.add(bSvigi2);
        bEqual.setBounds(200, 190, 70, 30);
        pnl.add(bEqual);
        //seperators & textfield
        sep1.setBounds(20, 50, 330, 10);
        pnl.add(sep1);
        sep2.setBounds(190, 60, 10, 160);
        pnl.add(sep2);
        txt.setBounds(70, 10, 280, 30);
        pnl.add(txt);
        add(pnl);

        //Setjum inní Menu
        file.add(deg);
        file.add(rad);
        file.add(trigon);
        menuBar.add(file);
        getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //HLUTIR SYNILEGIR
        setVisible(true);

        //NUMBER LISTENER
        ActionListener numberListener = new NumberListener();
        b0.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b1.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b2.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b3.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b4.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b5.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b6.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b7.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b8.addActionListener(numberListener);
        b9.addActionListener(numberListener);
        bDecPoint.addActionListener(numberListener);
        //bSvigi1.addActionListener(numberListener);
        //bSvigi2.addActionListener(numberListener);

        //OPERATOR LISTENER
        ActionListener operatorListener = new OperatorListener();
        bPlus.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bMinus.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bDivide.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bMult.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bSqrt.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bPower.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bEqual.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bxRoot.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        bPer.addActionListener(operatorListener);
        if(trigOpen){
        t.bCos.addActionListener(operatorListener); 
        }
        //ANS LISTENER
        ActionListener ansListener = new AnsListener();
        bAns.addActionListener(ansListener);

        //CLEAR LISTENER
        ActionListener clearListener = new ClearListener();
        bc.addActionListener(clearListener);

        //Menu LISTENER
        ActionListener menuListener = new MenuListener();
        trigon.addActionListener(menuListener);

        //RadioButton LISTENER
        ActionListener radioListener = new RadioListener();
        deg.addActionListener(radioListener);
        //RadioButton LISTENER 2
        ActionListener radioListener2 = new RadioListener2();
        rad.addActionListener(radioListener2);


    }
    /**E: Núllstillir
    private void action() {
        number = true; 
        txt.setText("0.0");
        equalOp  = "=";
        op.setTotal("0.0");
    }  */

    //VIRKNI RADIO TAKKANS SEM BREYTIR YFIR Í GRÁÐUR
    class RadioListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            degPressed = true;
        }
    }

    //VIRKNI RADIO TAKKANS SEM BREYTIR YFIR Í RADÍANA
    class RadioListener2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            degPressed = false;
        }
    }

    //VIRKNI CLEAR TAKKANS
    class ClearListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            txt.setText("0.0");
        }
    }


    //VIRKNI TRIGONMETRY FLIPA
    class MenuListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            t = new Trigonmetry();
            trigOpen = true;
        }
    }

    //VIRKNI ANS TAKKA
    class AnsListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ansOp = e.getActionCommand();
            if (ansOp.equals("ANS")) {
                txt.setText(ans);
            }
            else
                txt.setText("0.0");
        }
    }


    //VIRKNI TALNA TAKKA
    class NumberListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String digit = event.getActionCommand(); 
            if (number){
                txt.setText(digit);
                number = false;
            } 
            else{
                txt.setText(txt.getText() + digit);
            }
        }
    }   

    // VIRKNI "VIRKJA"
    class OperatorListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (number){
                //action();
                txt.setText("0.0");
            }
            else{
                number = true; 
                String displayText = txt.getText();
                if (equalOp.equals("=")) {
                op.setTotal(displayText);
                } 
                else if (equalOp.equals("+")) {
                    op.add(displayText);
                } 
                else if (equalOp.equals("-")) {
                    op.subtract(displayText);
                } 
                else if (equalOp.equals("*")) {
                    op.multiply(displayText);
                } 
                else if (equalOp.equals("/")) {
                    op.divide(displayText);
                }
                else if(equalOp.equals("x^n")){
                    op.power(displayText);
                }
                else if(equalOp.equals("√x")){
                    op.squareRoot(displayText);
                }
                else if(equalOp.equals("n√x")){
                    op.xRoot(displayText);
                }
                else if(equalOp.equals("%")){
                    op.perCent(displayText);
                }
            //  else if(t.operand.equals("cos")){
                //  if(degPressed){
                    //  op.cOsDeg(displayText);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //  op.cOs(displayText);
                //}
                //else if(equalOp.equals("sin")){
                //  op.sIn(displayText);
                //}
                //else if(equalOp.equals("tan")){
                //  op.tAn(displayText);
                //}
                txt.setText("" + op.getTotalString());
                ans = txt.getText();
                equalOp = e.getActionCommand();
                //t.operand = e.getActionCommand();

            }
        }
    }   

    //*************** MAIN ***************//
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Calculator calc = new Calculator();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my Tigonmetry class, as you can see I tried to set an actionListener there also

```
public class Trigonmetry extends JFrame
{
    JFrame frm;                  //rammi
    public JButton bCos;         //Cosinus
    public JButton bSin;         //Sinus
    public JButton bTan;         //Tangens
    public JButton baCos;        //arc Cosinus
    public JButton baSin;        //arc Sinus
    public JButton baTan;        //arc Tangens
    private JPanel panel;        //Panel
    public String operand;
    public Calculator cal;
    private CalculatorOp opp = new CalculatorOp();

    public Trigonmetry(){
        InitialUI();
    }

    public final void InitialUI(){
        frm = new JFrame(); 
        operand = "";
        bCos = new JButton("cos");
        bSin = new JButton("sin");
        bTan = new JButton("tan");
        baCos = new JButton("acos");
        baSin = new JButton("asin");
        baTan = new JButton("atan");
        panel = new JPanel();

        //HÖNNUN RAMMA
        setTitle("Trigonmetry");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(180, 110));
        panel.setLayout(null);

        //TAKKAR
        bSin.setBorder(null);
        bSin.setBounds(20, 10, 40, 30);
        panel.add(bSin);
        bCos.setBorder(null);
        bCos.setBounds(70, 10, 40, 30);
        panel.add(bCos);
        bTan.setBorder(null);
        bTan.setBounds(120, 10, 40, 30);
        panel.add(bTan);
        baCos.setBorder(null);
        baCos.setBounds(20, 50, 40, 30);
        panel.add(baCos);
        baSin.setBorder(null);
        baSin.setBounds(70, 50, 40, 30);
        panel.add(baSin);
        baTan.setBorder(null);
        baTan.setBounds(120, 50, 40, 30);
        panel.add(baTan);
        add(panel);


        //HLUTIR SYNILEGIR
        setVisible(true);

        //OPERATORLISTENER
        ActionListener operandListener = new OperandListener();
        bCos.addActionListener(operandListener);
        bSin.addActionListener(operandListener);
        bTan.addActionListener(operandListener);
    }
        // VIRKNI "VIRKJA"
    class OperandListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (cal.number){
                //action();
                cal.txt.setText("0.0");
            }
            else{
                cal.number = true; 
                String displayText1 = cal.txt.getText();
                if (cal.equalOp.equals("=")) {
                opp.setTotal(displayText1);
                } 
                else if(operand.equals("cos")){
                    if(cal.degPressed){
                        opp.cOsDeg(displayText1);
                    }
                    else
                        opp.cOs(displayText1);
                }
                else if(operand.equals("sin")){
                    if(cal.degPressed){
                        opp.sInDeg(displayText1);
                    }
                    else
                        opp.sIn(displayText1);
                }
                else if(operand.equals("tan")){
                    if(cal.degPressed){
                        opp.tAnDeg(displayText1);
                    }
                    else
                        opp.tAn(displayText1);
                }
                cal.txt.setText("" + opp.getTotalString());
                operand = e.getActionCommand();
            }
        }
    }   


}
```

Comment: Too much code to read. Don't use `setBounds()` to position and size components. Use a Layout Manager. Also, a popup window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame. If you fix these two problems then I might take a look at the problem later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Trigonometry's Calculator variable, cal, is null because it was never initialized with the current Calculator instance. You need to get the Calculator instance into the Trigonometry class so that the Trig class can call the public methods of the Calculator. One way to do this is via a constructor parameter, and another way is via a setter method such as `setCalculator(Calculator calculator) {...}`. An example of the constructor parameter technique:

in Calculator.java:

```
Trigonometry t = new Trigonometry(this);
```

and in Trigonometry class:

```
// constructor now accepts a Calculator parameter
public Trigonmetry(Calculator calculator) {
  // initialize the cal field with the current Calculator instance
  cal = calculator; 
  InitialUI();
}
```

Also:

- Don't use `setBounds(...)` and null layout as per camickr's recommendation.
- Instead read up on the use of layout managers and then use nested JPanels that each use an appropriate layout manager.
- Don't use more than one JFrame. The second Trig window should be a JDialog (also per camickr's recommendation).
- Learn and use Java coding conventions. Class names start with an upper case letter and method and variable names a lower-case letter.
- When asking questions here, try to pare your code down to the bare minimum that shows your problem, still allows your code to compile and run, but contains no code unrelated to your problem. 95% of your current code posted above is unnecessary to solving the problem and distracting for us.

Also:

- If you only want the Trigonometry instance to open under the control of Calculator, then don't have the code to show it called by Trigonometry but rather by Calculator.  In other words, don't have Trigonometry call `setVisible(true)` on itself, but rather have Calculator call this on the Trigonometry instance.

In Calculator:

```
class MenuListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     t.setVisible(true);
     trigOpen = true;
  }
}
```

In Trigonometry:

```
public final void InitialUI() { // this should be named initialUi()

  // ..... code deleted for brevity

  panel.add(baTan);
  add(panel);
  // !!  setVisible(true); // *** don't call this here ***
  ActionListener operandListener = new OperandListener();

  // ..... code deleted for brevity

}
```

Comment: @user1946287: You're welcome, but next time, please less *unrelated* code. Try creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) if you have similar problems.